# How can I convert mass percentage to atomic percentage?

Tags: chemical-compounds

How can I convert mass percentage to atomic percentage?

I have EDX (energy dispersive X-ray) analysis for a thin film, the results are in ms% (mass percentage), how can I convert mass percentage to atomic percentage?

Answer (score 1):

I assume by 'atomic percentages' you mean *molar percentages* aka *molar fractions*.

If $p_i$ is the mass percentage of each constituent then (with $n$ the total number of constituents):

$$\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^np_i=100 $$

Call $A_i$ the **atomic mass** of each constituent, then the number of moles $n_i$ of $i$ in $100\:\mathrm{g}$ of sample is:

$$n_i=\frac{p_i}{A_i}$$

The total number of moles in $100\:\mathrm{g}$ is:

$$N=\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n\frac{p_i}{A_i}$$

The molar fraction $\chi_i$ of each constituent is:

$$\chi_i=\frac{n_i}{N}$$

Multiply by $100$ to get percentages:

$$\chi_i=\frac{p_i}{NA_i}\times 100$$